# Calc Trig identity help I think?

Tags: trigonometry

Professor gave an answer key where she simplified from:

$$\sqrt {2\sin^2(t) +3\cos^2(t)}$$ To:

$$\sqrt {2+\cos^2(t)}$$ .

There's no explanation given beyond this but I'm assuming she's using trig identities somehow. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  $\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)=1$.

Comment: Did you try Pythagoras?

Comment: @lulu We seem to be making the same comments today :) Was just about to say that

Comment: @ZacharySelk  I have always preferred the proverb about great minds thinking alike then the one about fools never differing....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=1$ and so $$\sqrt{2\sin^2t+3\cos^2t}=\sqrt{2\sin^2t+2\cos^2t+\cos^2t}=\sqrt{2(\sin^2t+\cos^2t)+\cos^2t}=\sqrt{2+\cos^2t}.$$